# SharePoint 2013 OWA Web Parts and Outlook Web App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, outlook-web-app

I've got a big problem. I'm trying to implement in sharepoint 2013 online a web part using owa, Outlook Web Access, but it seems that nothing is working. I tried many and many solutions, but no good at all. Does anyone have ever try to do something like this before?
Does anyone has a possibile workaround?

It would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tryied it..but maybe this could be helpful for your purpose, try to have a look a this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2012/07/06/owa-web-part-in-an-iframe-sample.aspx

Comment: I try your solution, but i can't insert the iframe tag in my page there is something similar?

Comment: @SergioPetrarca Try to insert a webpart named Page Visualizer, it should automatically add an Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this:

```
https://127.0.0.1/public/test%20team%20calendar
```

Would need to be written something like this:

```
https://127.0.0.1/owa/?cmd=contents&module=PublicFolders&fpath=test%20team%20calendar
```

Here are some articles which you should review around developing with **OWA in an iFrame** or usage of **OWA Web parts**.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what are you trying to say to me, how can I implement my solution? You answered with a link to a Localhost...So what?

Comment: this look that 's right for you:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2012/07/06/owa-web-part-in-an-iframe-sample.aspx